# htaccess redirect all 404 not found to a specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all `404 not found`to a specific URL which is more relavant to user experience.

This redirect to a specific index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I redirect all 404 not found pages instead of index.php to a specific URL like: https://www.example.com/jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/ 
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/ 
# or map them to one error document: 
# ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php 
# ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L] 
# or map them to one error document: 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ [OR] 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$ 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/error_redirect
```

hope this helps:)

Comment: Not working in my WordPress website. I restart Apache, but not working.

Comment: This is only rule that can be suggested.